# Why doesn't this function actually update anything?

Tags: postgresql

This is a SQL learning exercise. I have a 'tbl' with a single integer field. There are no indices on this table. I have this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rcs()                                                                                     
    RETURNS VOID AS $$                                                                                               
DECLARE                                                                                                              
    c CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY sequence;                                                                
    s INTEGER;                                                                                                       
    r RECORD;                                                                                                        
BEGIN                                                                                                                
    s := 0;                                                                                                          
    OPEN c;                                                                                                          
    LOOP                                                                                                             
        FETCH c INTO r;                                                                                              
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;                                                                                         
        RAISE NOTICE 'got it';                                                                                       
        r.sequence = s;                                                                                              
        s := s + 1;                                                                                                  
        RAISE NOTICE '%', r.sequence;                                                                                
    END LOOP;                                                                                                        
    CLOSE c;                                                                                                         
END;                                                                                                                 
$$ language 'plpgsql'
```

This loads and runs cleanly and the RAISE statements suggest that the 'sequence' field gets updated to 0, 1 etc. in accordance with the ORDER BY.

However, when I SELECT the table afterwards, the pre-existing values (which happen to all be '6') did not change.

Is this something to do with transactions? I tried fiddling around with COMMIT, etc. to no avail.

This is a freshly installed Postgresql 9.4.4 running on a Linode with no hackery of config files or anything like that, from the 'psql' command line.

EDIT: maybe it's because 'r' isn't actually the DB table, it's some kind of temporary copy of it? If so, please clarify, hopefully what I'm trying to achieve here is obvious (and I know it may be a bit nonsensical, but surely it's possible without resorting to reading the set into Java, etc.)

Comment: You aren't actually updating the table. You are generating a record set, looping through it using a cursor, incrementing an integer variable, and then exiting. You will need an `UPDATE` statement to make changes to the table.

Comment: I just noticed that I meant for 'r.sequence = s' to be 'r.sequence := s' (colon added), though it doesn't make any difference. So -- with the colon, what exactly is that statement doing? Is it just an expression that goes nowhere? It's intriguing to me that the RAISE suggests that the update worked (with or without the colon).

Comment: What you are doing is known as the pattern "slow-by-slow" update. You can get rid of the function and do everything in a single update statement. That will be much more efficient and faster.

Comment: Oh, I see, I think the answer is as I said in the edit - 'r' is a local, temporary copy of the record, not the actual record in the database. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I have no doubt that that is true, but I have read at least 5 ways to do this, and none of them actually worked for my exact scenario (which IRL includes a unique index on 'sequence', omitted for sake of simplicity in this question). 'UPDATE ... ORDER BY' would work, but it's not available in Postgres. I'll keep trying ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem: your function does not contain an `UPDATE` statement so nothing gets written to disk. `r.sequence = s;` simply assigns a new value to a variable that is held *in memory*.

To fix this, you need something like:

```
UPDATE tbl
   set sequence = s -- change the actual column in the table
WHERE current of c; -- for the current row of your cursor
```

If `where current of` doesn't work, you need to switch that to a "regular" `where` clause:

```
UPDATE tbl
   set sequence = s 
WHERE tbl.pk_column = r.pk_column; -- the current primary key value
```

---

But a much more efficient solution is to do this in a single statement:

```
update tbl
   set sequence = tu.new_sequence
from ( 
    select t.pk_column, 
           row_number() over (order by t.sequence) as new_sequence
    from tbl t
) tu
where tbl.pk_column = tu.pk_column;
```

You need to replace the column name `pk_column` with the real primary key (or unique) column of your table.

Comment: Thanks a lot and again. I tried a 'update where current of' variation which didn't like the complexity of the WHERE that's IRL. Your second suggestion above is a new one to me and I deeply appreciate your taking the time.

Comment: @GregT: if `update where current of` doesn't work, then you need to select the primary key column and do an `where pk_column = `

Comment: Understood, appreciated, the clean efficient solution worked fine, I learned a lot from this. Thanks again.